# Is it possible to link different uses of Tor by using normal changes to the browser (such as bookmarks)?

Tags: anonymity, security, attacks, fingerprinting, deanonymization

Is it possible to link different Tor identies (uses of Tor at different times) by using the Bookmarks, settings of various components of the browser, or cosmetic alterations to the toolbars?

It has occured to me that a persons Bookmarks would act as a unique fingerprint, so would various modifications most people make to their browser in the normal course of use. Is their any way an attacker could access that data?

Answer (score 1):

The browser modifications that are available to websites can definitely act as a fingerprint and should be avoided. Plugins, browser addons and anything that changes the dimension of toolbars may fall into this category.

On the other hand, websites cannot access your bookmarks. But I would never store random bookmarks in my Tor Browser since they may include unique identifiers or scripts that may be used to link your identity across different sessions.

Comment: Could simple cosmetic changes like moving the buttons around produce this effect, or would it have to be an add-on that was not already in the Tor Browser?